# Testing best practices of Nodejs shared instances

Tags: node.js

i have application with logging and caching fetures, i created a utils directory to add `cache.js` and `logger.js`, `index.js` that exports both

`cache.js` example

```
const cache = require('cache');
module.exports = new cache({ /* my settings & dependencies here */});
```

`logger.js` example

```
const logger = require('logger');
module.exports = new logger({ /* my settings & dependencies here */});
```

`index.js` example of utils directory

```
const cache = require('cache');
const logger = require('logger');

module.exports = {cache, logger};
```

i made that to import any util from single file like:

```
const { logger} = require('./utils');
```

my problem is that, when i make a test file for logger i import logger as

```
const { logger} = require('./utils');
```

then a cache instance is made also, and i don't need that, because caching depend on **redis** connection that is not available on this context

Thanks

Comment: Use module mocking. Jest or else.

Comment: why will i mock cache from utils/index.js and i don't need it at all

Comment: Because *i don't need that, because caching depend on redis connection that is not available on this context*, as you said?